# ERROR: column reference "customer" is ambiguous

Tags: sql, postgresql

**GOAL**

I'm performing a counter on the hostname column for every client like BRASILFOODS, one thing I wanted was the side by side of the BRASILFOODS count.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) hostname, customer
FROM tb_get_gap
LEFT JOIN tb_get_customers
ON tb_get_gap.customer = tb_get_customers.cust_cmdb WHERE tb_get_customers.customer = 'BRASILFOODS' and tb_get_gap.exception = 'NO';
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>[Error] Script lines: 1-4 --------------------------
 ERROR: column reference "customer" is ambiguous
 Line: 1
```

Comment: both tables have a column `customer`. The `SELECT` statement cannot decide which one you want to show. So define the relevant table: `SELECT one_of_both_tables.customer`

Comment: and add `GROUP BY one_of_both_tables.customer`

Comment: very good, thanks!

SELECT tb_get_gap.customer, COUNT(*) hostname
FROM tb_get_gap
LEFT JOIN tb_get_customers
ON tb_get_gap.customer = tb_get_customers.cust_cmdb WHERE tb_get_customers.customer = 'FLEURY' and tb_get_gap.exception = 'NO'
GROUP BY tb_get_gap.customer;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    tgg.customer,                     -- 1
    COUNT(*) 
FROM tb_get_gap tgg 
LEFT JOIN tb_get_customers tgc 
    ON tgg.customer = tgc.cust_cmdb 
WHERE tgc.customer = 'BRASILFOODS' 
    AND tgg.exception = 'NO' 
GROUP BY tgg.customer                 -- 2
```

1. "*ambiguous*" means, that there is an identifier which can be gotten from several sources. In this case both of your tables contain a column with the name `customer`. So you have specify which of both you want to show by adding the table identifier or alias.
2. You are using an aggregate function (`COUNT(*)`). It seems that you want to get a count by `customer`. So in this case you need to group by this column.

Answer (score 1):

Which customer column are you trying to get? 
`tb_get_gap.customer` or `tb_get_customers.customer`?

That's why you're getting the ambiguous reference error. You need to indicate from which table you want it.

Comment: tb_get_gap.customer = BRASILFOODS

CUSTOMER = BRASILFOODS | COUNT = 30

Comment: Replace ``customer`` in your SELECT with ``tb_get_gap.customer``.

Comment: SELECT tb_get_gap.customer, COUNT(*) hostname
FROM tb_get_gap
LEFT JOIN tb_get_customers
ON tb_get_gap.customer = tb_get_customers.cust_cmdb WHERE tb_get_customers.customer = 'FLEURY' and tb_get_gap.exception = 'NO'
output: 
 ERROR: column "tb_get_gap.customer" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function